# MDLS | MetaData | Unable to grab kMDItemVersion of Illustrator File

Tags: macos, metadata, adobe-illustrator, mdls

I'm attempting to display a files version using `mdls -name kMDItemVersion filepath` but it's returning `null`.

If I simpy run `mdls filepath` the kMDItemVersion is not displayed for the file.

The weird part is that I can view the version info by right-clicking and selecting get info.

Normally I would use kMDItemCreator but .ai files don't appear to add that specific metadata unlike most other apps.

Sadly I don't have enough points to post pics. It's important to know that the .ai files clearly displays the following under get info > general.

```
Version: Saves As v.17 Created by v. 18.0.0
```

This is exactly the info I'm after.

Links to pics below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DtNt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJc2x.png